# Change format JSON output in file?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, json, file

I have the next PHP code that makes me a JSON file with data from my SQL table:

```
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost','root','xxxx','xxxx');
$myArray = array();
$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT CONCAT(Datum , ' ', Tijd) as Datum, KleurL FROM metingen order by Datum ASC limit 20");
if ($result) {
  $tempArray = array();
  while ($row = $result->fetch_object()) {
    $tempArray = $row;
    array_push($myArray, $tempArray);
  }
  echo json_encode($myArray,JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
  $fp = fopen('resultsv2.json', 'w');
  fwrite($fp, json_encode($myArray,JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK));
  fclose($fp);
}
$result->close();
$mysqli->close();
?>
```

The ouput of the JSON file looks like this.:

```
[{"Datum":"17-01-2019 10:31:39","KleurL":17.68},{"Datum":"17-01-2019 11:10:59","KleurL":71.76},{"Datum":"18-01-2019 08:40:41","KleurL":70.7},{"Datum":"18-01-2019 10:30:01","KleurL":71.03},{"Datum":"18-01-2019 12:05:46","KleurL":70.56},{"Datum":"18-01-2019 14:31:58","KleurL":16.2}]
```

But I would like to see that the output of that file looks like this.:

```
[
  [
    17.68,
    17-01-2019 10:31:39
  ],
  [
    18.11,
    17-01-2019 11:15:20
  ]
]
```

How can I get this output in the JSON file?

Comment: So, basically you are trying to reformat the json output, right?

Comment: If its possible, yes.

Comment: Do you want quotes around `17-01-2019 10:31:39` and `17.68` or not?

Comment: Also, do you want each object to be wrapped in [ 17.68,
    17-01-2019 10:31:39 ] (like your output) or { 17.68,
    17-01-2019 10:31:39 } (like JSON) ?

Comment: I want , if its possible, the output file like the last layout and not what i have at this moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code should achieve what you are trying to do. This code was tested on my pc and seems to be working perfectly.

```
<?php $mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', 'xxxx', 'xxxx');
if ($result = $mysqli->query("SELECT CONCAT(Datum , ' ', Tijd) as Datum, KleurL FROM metingen order by Datum ASC limit 20")) {
    $current_row_number = 0;

    $output = "[";
    while ($row = $result->fetch_object()) {
        if ($current_row_number > 0) {
            $output = $output . ","; //add comma between each row
        }

        $output = $output . "[" . $row->KleurL . "," . $row->Datum . "]"; //add each row

        $current_row_number++;
    }
    $output = $output . "]";

    echo $output;

    $fp = fopen('resultsv2.json', 'w');
    fwrite($fp, $output);
    fclose($fp);
}

$result->close();
$mysqli->close();
```

If you want to format the output nicely, use the following code:

```
<?php $mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '244466666', 'tkd');
if ($result = $mysqli->query("SELECT CONCAT(Datum , ' ', Tijd) as Datum, KleurL FROM metingen order by Datum ASC limit 20")) {
    $current_row_number = 0;

    $output = "[";
    while ($row = $result->fetch_object()) {
        if ($current_row_number > 0) {
            $output = $output . ","; //add comma between each row
        }

        $output = $output . "\n\t" . "[" . "\n\t\t" . $row->KleurL . "," . "\n\t\t" . $row->Datum . "\n\t" . "]"; //add each row

        $current_row_number++;
    }
    $output = $output . "\n]";

    // echo $output; //if you want to see the output in the terminal/command prompt
    echo "<pre>" . $output . "</pre>"; //if you want to see the output in a browser

    $fp = fopen('resultsv2.json', 'w');
    fwrite($fp, $output);
    fclose($fp);
}

$result->close();
$mysqli->close();
```

Comment: Thx, Tanmoy its looking mutch better know but, what you said, the quots must go away and stil { instead of [. This is how my output file looks now.: [
    {
        "KleurL": 17.68,
        "Datum": "17-01-2019 10:31:39"
    },
    {
        "KleurL": 71.76,
        "Datum": "17-01-2019 11:10:59"
    }
] the name KleurL and Datum may also be left away if possible.

Comment: Okay, I'm taking a look at it.

Comment: No not exactly. Stil it looks like this.: {
        "KleurL": 16.4,
        "Datum": "19-01-2019 16:30:59"
    } But i would like to see this.: [
         16.4,
        19-01-2019 16:30:59
    ]

Comment: I tryed with echo str_replace( '{', '[', '', $output);  but i don't see any changes.

Comment: Okay... I'll take a look at that.

Comment: I fixed the code. I made a silly mistake previously. Instead of accessing object properties, I was accessing array elements. I have tested the current code in my computer. Now it should work perfectly.

Comment: Thx Tanmoy , now its looks the same, but now i have two new problems. First i have no layout on my page , i don't see any values but only in the json file and second in the json file [[17.68,17-01-2019 10:31:39],[71.76,17-01-2019 11:10:59],[70.70,18-01-2019 08:40:41],[71.03,18-01-2019 10:30:01],[70.56,18-01-2019 12:05:46],[16.20,18-01-2019 14:31:58],[16.60,19-01-2019 15:35:16],[16.40,19-01-2019 16:30:59],[16.84,19-01-2019 17:36:16]] and not nice under eatch other so what you had before.

Comment: So, what you mean is you want the output string to be formatted nicely, right?

Comment: I added another code below the previous code for formatting the output with indentations and new lines. Take a look.

Comment: Ow Tanmoy tank you so mutch!!! its just what i wanted. I need that data in this format to use it in a chart. My next problem is that the chart is'nt showing the data, but i think i need to open a new topic for this problem

Comment: If this solves your problem, mark it as the correct answer so that in future other people who are facing the same problem can be benefitted from this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `json_encode() JSON_PRETTY_PRINT` options:

```
json_encode($myArray,JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK | JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

edit:

if you are using windows, you need to change the carriage return using something like this:

```
$myArray = array("test" => "data");

$buffer = json_encode($myArray,JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK | JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);

echo str_replace("\n", "\r\n", $buffer);
// or
$fp = fopen('resultsv2.json', 'w');
fwrite($fp, str_replace("\n", "\r\n", $buffer));
fclose($fp);
```

If you are printing this into the browser you need to use `<pre>` tags

```
<pre>
echo json_encode($myArray,JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK | JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
</pre>
```

Comment: I do not see any difference in the data thats shown, only after an extra space

Comment: Did you print it to browser? If you print it to browser you need to enclose the output with the `<pre>` tag. If you re on windows you need to change the carriage return, see the edit to the answer